# How to Force using my ID on category, not the auto-increment of prestashop category. PrestaShop

Tags: php, xml, web-services, prestashop

I want to define my own Category id like(999,2222,3333) and force using it on the PrestaShop database but when I execute it does(1,2,3)
How can I force using my own id

```
        foreach ($XMLRSString->Families->Family as $family)
        {   
            $_GET['forceIDs'] = true;

            $category = new Category($family->Code);

            $category->id = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') =>  $family->Code);

            $category->id_category = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') =>  $family->Code);

            $category->id_category_default = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') =>  $family->Code);

            $category->is_root_category = false;

            $category->name = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $family->Designation);

            $category->id_parent = Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY');

            $category->link_rewrite = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') =>  $family->Code);

            $category->add();

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PrestaShop, if you'd like to force the ID of a specific object (Category, Product, Order, etc.) to bypass the SQL auto-increment during DB insertion, you have to set the `force_id` parameter to true.

**Here's a minimalist example that works for a Category:**

```
$category = new Category();
$category->id = 42;
$category->force_id = true;
$category->is_root_category = false;
$category->name = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => 'Test');
$category->link_rewrite = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') =>  'test');
$category->id_parent = Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY');
$category->add();
```

This will work with all versions of PrestaShop and can be found in the ObjectModel class (parent class for all Objects):

```
/** @var bool Enables to define an ID before adding object. */
public $force_id = false;
```

It is then checked right before adding the object in DB, in the same class:

```
public function add($auto_date = true, $null_values = false)
{
    if (isset($this->id) && !$this->force_id)
        unset($this->id);

    ...
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: oh, nice Thank-q sop much! It works in perfection :)